# Sum of array in groups excluding potential nil items

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, nil, 7, 8, 9, nil, nil, 12]
```

How can i get an array of the sums of these numbers in groups of 4, so that when a nil is encountered, it's treated as zero?

So that the outcome would be:

```
[10, 20, 21]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work (probably there are more efficient solutions):

```rb
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, nil, 7, 8, 9, nil, nil, 12]

array.each_slice(4).map { |slice| slice.sum(&:to_i) }
#=> [10, 20, 21]
```

Comment: Suggestion: `slice.compact.sum`

Comment: I might have written it this way a few years ago, when I was just a kid, but now I'd write `def sum_with_nils(arr); arr.sum { |e| e.nil? ? 0 : e }; end`, then `array.each_slice(4).map { |slice| sum_with_nils(slice) } #=> [10, 20, 21]`. It's arguably easier to read, but mainly, easier to test.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer working with indices directly, you could:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, nil, 7, 8, 9, nil, nil, 12]

(0...a.size).step(4).map { |i| a[i...i+4].compact.sum }
# => [10, 20, 21]
```